# Between And Greater Than Date Should Be Implement In Same Query

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have two DateTime columns like `start_datetime` and `end_datetime`. these fields contain DateTime value.

[image]

Here itself I need three different outputs. while you search, "15-09-2020 00:00:00" to "26-09-2020 23:59:59" it will display the first two lines. if you search like "26-09-2020 00:00:00" to "13-10-2020 23:59:59", it should result in three rows.

Instead of if you search, "10-09-2020 00:00:00" to "18-09-2020 23:59:59", it will show the first two rows.

In this case, I am stuck at the query. if I am using between some results won't come. if I am using greater than a symbol, some results won't come.

Comment: Either store dates using a date data type, or don't bother with an RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store the date time format in YYYY-MM-DD H:I:S, so you can easily

```
 SELECT *
      FROM table_name
      WHERE start_datetime BETWEEN value1 AND value2 AND end_datetime BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Comment: yes i am storing the result which you have mentioned. but it responds only between dates.

Comment: but some of my clients has been searching like, 14-09-2020 00:00:00 to 20-09-2020 23:59:59, result is empty. during that time, it should show two rows according to them. but it didn't satisfy the condition of greater or lesser than option.

Comment: you can store your format too, but think when year will change how will query can finds the correct result.?